# What is the maximum allowed rows in a Microsoft Excel .xls or .xlsx

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there a limit? I couldn't find one posted.

Comment: Hmmmm.....doesn't this depend on whether 32-bit or 64-bit version is being used?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Have a look at this [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20080313035725/http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP051992911033.aspx?mode=print)** and [this one](http://web.archive.org/web/20140819001409/http://news.office-watch.com/t/n.aspx?articleid=1408&zoneid=9) (and [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HA103980614.aspx) for 2013). A quick summary:

```
+-----------------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
|                 | Max. Rows | Max. Columns | Max. Cols by letter |
+-----------------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
| Excel 365*      | 1,048,576 | 16,384       | XFD                 |
| Excel 2013      | 1,048,576 | 16,384       | XFD                 |
| Excel 2010      | 1,048,576 | 16,384       | XFD                 |
| Excel 2007      | 1,048,576 | 16,384       | XFD                 |
| Excel 2003      | 65,536    | 256          | IV                  |
| Excel 2002 (XP) | 65,536    | 256          | IV                  |
| Excel 2000      | 65,536    | 256          | IV                  |
| Excel 97        | 65,536    | 256          | IV                  |
| Excel 95        | 16,384    | 256          | IV                  |
| Excel 5         | 16,384    | 256          | IV                  |
+-----------------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
```

*Excel 365 unverified.

**This (web archive) link probably will not work with your browser, but the information is in the page source.

Comment: Links are apparently dead. This answer, though it does in fact provide most of the information, indicates the limitations of *Excel*, and not of the supported file formats *xls* or *xlsx*. The limitations of *xls* is still 256 columns and 65536 rows, if you use that file format in a newer Excel version.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Thanks for the update. It looks like the second link is still alive, but I have noted that the first link is dead.

Comment: MS doesn't seem to have the 2003 and before specs anymore, but on Wayback you can sort of get to them... http://web.archive.org/web/20080313035725/http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP051992911033.aspx?mode=print for example (I edited that in).

Answer (score 22):

You can find out how many rows your version of Excel supports by opening a new file in Excel then pressing  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> in an empty worksheet.

This number of rows can be saved in the default format that version of Excel supports (e.g. XLSX).

However, you will not necessarily be able to save in the older XLS format, which is still limited to 65,536 rows. Typing in a cell in row number 1048576 (e.g. A1048576) then saving to XLS format will cause a warning. If you close and re-open this file, you will then find this cell empty.

Answer (score 16):

Doing a web search for "maximum number of rows in Excel" gives a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700514.aspx) (several, actually) with

> Starting in Excel 2007, the "Big Grid" increases the maximum number of rows per worksheet from 65,536 to over 1 million, and the number of columns from 256 (IV) to 16,384 (XFD).