# Is there an easy fix to this copy/paste into Excel error?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, database, memory-management, ole

When I attempt to paste a large spreadsheet (from a DB, ~90,000 rows) into Excel, I keep getting this error:

> Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE
>   action

[image]

I know there's a clipboard buffer area, but not much else. If I upgrade my computer's RAM, will it fix these types of errors?

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft Excel 2010 has a maximum of 65,536 rows per worksheet. I would export your database in two sections then transfer to excel. [referenced from here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx)

Comment: Hey my friend, thanks a lot! One small correction though, Excel 2010(my version of it) has actually  been upgraded - it's now about 1 mil - http://superuser.com/questions/366468/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-rows-in-a-microsoft-excel-xls-or-xlsx

Comment: Correct [here's the updated referenced link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005199291) are you stil having the error?

Comment: Hey, yeah I still am.. I'm not sure what but I'll try breaking it up as you suggested! I'll let you know what happens :)

Comment: The link applies to Excel 2003. [here](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005199291) are the new limits